# How to access my-app.js from pages in framework7?

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

i created a page in my-app.js
`routes: [ { path: '/tab1/', url: 'pages/tab1.html', pageInit: function (e, page) { console.log('ini'); //it doesn‘t work } ]`

i have an event in my-app.js
`$$('.ac-1').on('click', function () { console.log(1); });`

it works in index.html, BUT IN PAGE IT does‘t works!

Answer (score 0):

Your event probably does not work because it's linked to a dynamically created element; it's common on some old F7 version.

In order to have it working (quick and dirty) you can create a function in *my-app.js* and place a *onclick="myFunction()"* in your clickable element within *tab1.html*.

**Please note this is a quite inelegant solution, not to be used in production.**

**my-app.js**

```
function myFunction(){
   console.log1;
   }
```

**tab1.html**

```
<element class="ac-1" onclick="myFunction();">Click here</element>
```